# Find the steady state matrix for Markov Chains

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains

**Question:** Let $P$ be a transition matrix.  Suppose that

$$P^{k} =\begin{bmatrix}0.37 & 0.37 & 0.37\\0.33&0.33&0.33\\ 0.3&0.3&0.3\end{bmatrix}$$

As $k$ approaches infinity, if $x_k$ are state vectors and $x_0$ is a probability vector, then what does $x_k$ converges to?

---

**My attempt:** Since $Px=x$, we know that $(P - I_3)=x$. By subtracting $P$ with the identity matrix, I got:

$$(P - I_3) = x = \begin{bmatrix}-0.63&0.37&0.37\\ 0.33&-0.67&0.33\\ 0.3&0.3&-0.7\end{bmatrix}$$

For the next step, I generally find the null space of the matrix, which provide me with the info to find $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$. But in this case, solving for the reduced row echelon form of the matrix is nearly impossible and I'm not really sure how I should approach this problem.

Can someone please show me how this is done? Thanks in advance

Comment: $P-I_3$ is a $3\times3$ matrix, $x$ is a $3$-vector, right? So, $P-I_3=x$ doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steady state distribution is $(0.37,0.33,0.3)$ because for any distribution $x$, $Px$ is this distribution.